# Conduct PCA to assess proxy measurements of Likert-style scale

Tags: pca, ordinal-data, likert

I have a two-dimensional Likert-style scale and multiple proxy measurements thereof.

**Is it possible to compute a Principal Component Analysis to see which of the proxy measurements best reflect this Likert-style scale?**

I am aware that PCA is usually a technique to reduce the total amount of items in a questionnaire, but thought I can make respective deductions from the factor loadings of a Varimax rotated PCA.

I would continue by expanding the original Likert-style scale with the proxy measurements that show the highest loadings and subsequently test the internal reliability with the Cronbach's Alpha.

*Does that sound like a legitimate plan?*

Please note, that I am only looking into this in the scope of my thesis and have little to no statistic skills (thats also why I would want to avoid Structural Equation Modelling what seems to be the alternative).

Comment: I would use the proxies to predict the score, and select the set of proxies that best predct the score.

Comment: @JeremyMiles would you still do the same if you have reason to belief that the actual measurement is not a good fit? I thought I could increase internal reliability etc by expanding the measurement with items from the proxies if they are respectively loaded in a factor analysis

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: The 'actual measurement' is a two dimensional scale with one question per dimension. It's very explorative and not building on other existing scales, thus has (most likely) a low validity

Comment: It sounds like you might increase reliability at the cost of validity. But if your proxies aren't very good, they're not really proxies (at least as I would think of it)?

Comment: @JeremyMiles sorry for the late reply. Why would I sacrifice validity in that case? I'm measuring sth that has not yet been measured and there is no way (too little time) to do a second study with a control group or to measure the same group again at a later time (longitudinal study)